# Pending transfer

Tags: electrum, exodus

I sent some bitcoin from my Electrum wallet to Exodus app and the transfer is still pending after more than a day!

I chose the lowest fee possible, could that be the reason? And when I can I expect it confirm?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes low fee rate (according to the screenshot) is the reason for the transaction not being confirmed yet. However you can increase the fee rate and fees because this was RBF enabled transaction. The replacement transaction may get confirmed soon if it has fee rate above 50 sat/vByte. Or you can wait for this transaction to get confirmed which can take days.

I normally check the mempool stats in these 3 websites:

https://btc.bitaps.com

https://mempool.observer

https://mempool.space

Answer (score 1):

@Prayank confirmed that yes, it's your fee rate and provided some sites you can use to check the state of the mempool - and hence the fees that fit with your objectives - before sending the transaction.

Additionally, if you want to INCREASE the fee of your transaction AFTER you've sent it, there are a couple of ways to do it. The simplest way is called Replace By Fee (RBF) and the Electrum wallet does support this. Effectively you're going back to the wallet and selecting the transaction and increasing the fee. That then is the new increased fee for the transaction and may help it be confirmed sooner .. depending upon the new fee rate you select.

Comment: The way I read it, the user sent from Electrum to Exodus, so the question would be whether Electrum supports RBF, not Exodus.

Comment: Doh. Thanks Murch - yes you're correct. I should finish morning coffee before pontificating! Will amend.